# Best practice to store object with generic field into a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, generics

I'm implementing an application for private use in Android which request some data from server in JSON format, deselialize it to POJO and need to store objects in a local database. The problem is that `Child` class contains a generic value, also the value may be primitive type (integer, string, ...) or some custom objects. I tried [Realm](https://realm.io/), but i got [NPE](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3605). I have read about [EAV-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), but I'm not really satisfied with it.

What is the best way to store object containing generic values in a database? I'm not depend on a specific database, but would prefer SQLite.

Simple POJOs of data structure without `extends RealmObject`:

```
public class Parent {
    public int i;
    public Child mChild;
}
```

A class which contains generic field:

```
public class Child<T> {
    public int i;
    public T mValue;
}
```

A custom object:

```
public class Value {
    public int i;
    public String s;
}
```

An example trying Realm:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
p.i = 10;
// Child<String> c = new Child<>();
// c.mValue = "I'm a string!";
Child<Value> c = new Child<>();
Value v = new Value();
v.s = "I'm a custom object!";
v.i = 42;
p.mChild = c;

Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Parent parent = realm.copyToRealm(p);
    }
});
```

Comment: a quick and dirty solution would be to save a json representation of your child object, would that be an option?

Comment: I have think about something like that, for example to use CouchDB. But workflow would be like this: JSON -> POJO -> JSON (store in CouchDB) -> POJO (fetch results from CouchDB) I don't think this would be a solution.

Comment: well, it wouldn't be a nice solution xD

Comment: you can store `mChild` only as json in the table, and you may want to add extra field to tell which type this child is, (helps when deserialize) the downside for this is, if you want to query some data based on values from that JSON field, it will be useless , ex (where child.x = '1') you can't achieve this

Comment: I drift to use serialization for POJO objects implemented by [repository](https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006) pattern. I know there is no silver bullet, but I would like to know if somebody have the same problem, what experience he/she make.

Comment: @Yazan Interesting solution :) Fetching data by values in `Child` class have no priority.